# Why isn't my 'Version' column updating after approving a document?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'd very much appreciate some feedback here before I pull the last of my hair out!

I have a document library. Versioning and check out is enabled. Major versions only. The flow [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Ns7.jpg) seems to work correctly

I'm using the native 'Version' column, but it just stays empty, despite the document showing as Approved in the library. Any help here would be great!

TIA!

I have tried getting the meta data from the file before and after to see if that will update the Version but it doesn't work

Comment: Does it need to be Check-in after approval?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the response! I've tried with that. The flow starts when a file is created or modified, so when a user checks a file in, that starts the flow.

Comment: Could you manually check in and approve the file then check whether "Version" column update after approving a file?